# Using class to call jQuery UI date-picker doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, class, datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI datepicker - the range version. I have a form and in the input field (text) of the "from date" I call the datepicker. It works fine.

The problem is that I also have in that field an image (of a calendar) that I set it's class to be the same one as the field's. BUT, while the field open the datepicker without problems, clicking the image seems do do nothing.
I know there are some questions regarding this issue, but nothing helps ;)

```
<input type="text" id="fromDate" value="Enter date" name="fromDate" class="fromDatePicker"/>
<img class="fromDatePicker" src="images/calender_icon_a1.jpg" id="ci1"/>
```

The js code:

```
$(function() {
$( ".fromDatePicker" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    altFormat: 'yymmdd',
    altField: "#fromDateFormatted",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $('#toDate').datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can't bind a datepicker to an image. If we look at the [datepicker source, we see this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#L166):

```
if (nodeName == 'input') {
    this._connectDatepicker(target, inst);
} else if (inline) {
    this._inlineDatepicker(target, inst);
}
```

and `inline` is true if and only if `nodeName` is `div` or `span`. So when you try to bind the datepicker to an `<img>`, you get ignored without so much as a warning in the console.

If you look at the *Icon Trigger* example on the [jQuery-UI demos page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger), you'll see the approved way of activating the datepicker using an icon:

```
$('.fromDatePicker').datepicker({
    // existing options
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar_icon_a1.jpg", 
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

and then remove your `img.fromDatePicker` element entirely.